# What is the correct way to write pure virtual function without a specific return type?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, pure-virtual

I'm trying to write an abstract struct named `Shape`, and I need a function in derived classes that will be counting distance from a ray origin to my shape. I use functions [from here](https://iquilezles.org/articles/intersectors/), they return `float`, `vec2`, `vec3`, etc. I do this because I need to store these shapes in a vector of `BasePrimitive` later. Is this a good way?

```cpp
struct Shape {
    virtual void* Intersect(const vec3& ro, const vec3& rd) = 0; // ro - rayOrigin, rd - rayDirection
};

struct Sphere : public Shape {
    vec3 ce; // center
    float ra; // radius

    vec2 Intersect(const vec3& ro, const vec3& rd) override {
        // some code
    } 
};
```

I tried to do it via `void*`, but when I inserted `void*` I got an error:

> return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "void *" of overridden virtual function "Shape::Intersect"

Comment: But why do you need different return types? The distance is always a single number.

Comment: I use functions from https://iquilezles.org/articles/intersectors. Some of functions there have optional parameters that may be useful. I want to save them in derived classes of Shape.

Comment: The error message is correct.  You are promising that the return type will be `void*`, and then violating that promise.  This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What optional parameters, I'm asking about the return value. Do you actually need more than one value? Currently this sounds like you don't have a practical problem, just "I have those functions, and I want to make an inheritance hierarchy for them". Whatever code will be calling those functions through a base pointer will expect a fixed return type. You could have a second non-virtual function in each derived class that returns something else, then call it from the virtual function, keeping only one of the return values.

Comment: I understood that I forgot to mention in description that type may be not only float but vec2, vec3 and etc. I corrected it.

Comment: are the returns always one or more `float`s? Could you just return `std::vector<float>`?

Comment: @KapibarovichKapibarov The return type of an overriding method in a derived class MUST be either identical to, or covariant to (aka derived from), the return type of the base class method that is being overridden. There is no other option.  So you need to fix your design to return something that all classes involved can agree on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a function that can return **ANY TYPE**, one option is to do something like this:

```cpp
#include <any> // For 'std::any' and 'std::any_cast' (Since C++17)
#include <string>


class BC // Abstract polymorphic base class
{
public:

    virtual std::any f() = 0; // Pure virtual

    virtual ~BC() = default; // Virtual destructor (For an abstract polymorphic base class, it is highly recommended to provide a virtual destructor)
};


class DC1 final : public BC
{
public:

    std::any f() override
    {
        return 1.5; // double
    }
};


class DC2 final : public BC
{
public:

    std::any f() override
    {
        return std::string("Pluto"); // std::string
    }
};


class DC3 final : public BC
{
public:

    std::any f() override
    {
        return 0; // int
    }
};


int main()
{
    DC1 obj1{};
    const auto a = std::any_cast<double>(obj1.f());

    DC2 obj2{};
    const auto b = std::any_cast<std::string>(obj2.f());

    DC3 obj3{};
    const auto c = std::any_cast<int>(obj3.f());
}
```

- This solution is usually a poor choice, often stemming from poor design choices. Nevertheless, it remains a viable option, particularly in cases where it doesn't arise from poor design choices.

--

For a **SET OF TYPES** this is a better choice:

```cpp
#include <variant> // For 'std::variant' and 'std::get' (Since C++17)
#include <string>


class BC // Abstract polymorphic base class
{
public:
    using SetOfTypes = std::variant<double, std::string, int>;

    virtual SetOfTypes f() = 0; // Pure virtual

    virtual ~BC() = default; // Virtual destructor (For an abstract polymorphic base class, it is highly recommended to provide a virtual destructor)
};


class DC1 final : public BC
{
public:

    SetOfTypes f() override
    {
        return 1.5; // double
    }
};


class DC2 final : public BC
{
public:

    SetOfTypes f() override
    {
        return std::string("Pluto"); // std::string
    }
};


class DC3 final : public BC
{
public:

    SetOfTypes f() override
    {
        return 0; // int
    }
};


int main()
{
    DC1 obj1{};
    const auto a = std::get<double>(obj1.f());

    DC2 obj2{};
    const auto b = std::get<std::string>(obj2.f());

    DC3 obj3{};
    const auto c = std::get<int>(obj3.f());
}
```

Comment: Note that this is almost always a bad idea resulting from a design mistake. If you have to do this, stop and think through what lead you here.

Comment: `std::variant` would certainly be a better choice in this example than `std::any`

Comment: @RemyLebeau , 1st of all, I agree. But, OP asked for ANY type. std::variant is for a predefined set of types. At any case I added also the `std::variant` solution.

Comment: IMHO, a better method is to return values through parameters.  This allows for function overloading as an alternative method.